# Parallax effect on Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, parallax

I am thinking of giving a parallax effect to the Alert Dialog (Dialog) in one of my Android app. I searched a lot and found some sample project for parallax list view but couldn't find anything similar to what I need. I want the Dialog to look like as if its floating above the background. How can I achieve this parallax effect.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it?